# R Code Error - How To Rewrite Code Using Magrittr

Tags: r, magrittr

I cannot rewrite a piece of standard R code using magrittr

This works fine as standard R:

```
q1 <- tbl_df(read.csv('activity.csv',
                  header = TRUE,
                  sep = ',',
                  colClasses = c('numeric', 'POSIXct', 'numeric')))
```

But this does not using magrittr:

```
q1 <- 
    tbl_df(read.csv('activity.csv')) %>%
    header = TRUE %>%
    sep = ',' %>%
    colClasses = c('numeric', 'POSIXct', 'numeric')
```

```
Error in "," %>% colClasses = c("numeric", "POSIXct", "numeric") :
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I kind of understand the gist of the error, but don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%>%` is used to chain multiple operations, not to specify parameters (see `?'%>%'`). So stick to the first one. :-) Or use

```
read.csv('activity.csv', 
         header = TRUE, 
         sep = ',', 
         colClasses = c('numeric', 'POSIXct', 'numeric')) %>% 
  tbl_df()
```